# Como apagar o conteudo de um arquivo em c?

Tags: c

Como eu posso apagar o conteudo de um arquivo em c, qual função eu devo usar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
    char hello[13] = "Hello World!";
    char path[12] = "arquivo.txt";
    FILE* arquivo;
    arquivo = fopen(path, "a+");
    fprintf(arquivo, hello);
    printf("%s foi adicionado ao arquivo %s", hello, path);

    /*

    arquivo = fopen(path, "w");
    fclose(arquivo);

    */
}
```

Comment: Todo o conteúdo?

Comment: sim, apagar todo o conteudo de um arquivo de texto

Comment: Abrir o arquivo no modo `w` não apaga o conteúdo anterior?

Comment: É literalmente apenas fazer `fopen` com `w` como o @AndersonCarlosWoss disse

Comment: eu ja tentei abrir com o w, mas não apagou

Comment: E porque não apagar o arquivo pura e simplesmente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para apagar o conteúdo de um arquivo em C basta abrir com o modo `w`:

```
fopen(caminho_para_o_arquivo, "w");
```

Agora no seu caso acontece que já o abriu anteriormente com `a+`:

```
void main(){
    ...
    arquivo = fopen(path, "a+");
    ...
    arquivo = fopen(path, "w");
    fclose(arquivo);
}
```

Por isso a segunda tentativa abertura não apaga o conteúdo. Para corrigir coloque um `fclose` antes abrir novamente:

```
    arquivo = fopen(path, "a+");
    fclose(arquivo);
    ...
    arquivo = fopen(path, "w");
    fclose(arquivo);
```

Ou melhor nem abra para acrescentar conteúdo com `a+` já que de seguida vai apagar! Simplifique e deixe somente:

```
fclose(fopen(path, "w"));
```

Comment: eu criei esse codigo só para simplificar as coisas, agora funcionou, obrigado Isac